# Limit command mode mappings to start of commands

Tags: vim

By default, I want to open the help windows vertically. I'm able to do this with `:vert bo help`. To make things easier, I tried to create a map it by `:cnoremap vh vert bo help`. However, this replaces all instaces of vh. How do I limit it to changing only if is at the beginning?

I also tried using cabbrev. It is slightly better and waits till a space but suffers from the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `cmap`, you can use `command` which support TAB-completion:

#### for example:

```
:com! -nargs=1 -complete=help H :vert bo help <args>
```

Comment: kev, command forces you to use uppercase characters, doesn't it? Is there a way around that?